# I cannot stop AJAX from escaping request body I pass

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to pass an JSON request to a server, but AJAX escapes every character I pass. I do not want this.

For example, if I pass an empty object,

```
{}
```

the server received the escaped sequence

```
%7B%7D=
```

My AJAX call is:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://my-server-name.com:8002/store_test',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: "{}",
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

How could I  disable this escaping?

Comment: It should be `data: {}` (without quotes). It is an Object, not a string.

Comment: if I do it without quotes, body send to server is empty. I need to pass real data and "{}" is just an test to avoid default escaping. Any other ideas?

Comment: what does your developer console give you for the sent and received data?

Comment: @joro - that's because sending just `{}` is an empty object - i.e. nothing. If you send a non-empty object, then the request will not be empty.

Comment: it returns me POST <address> 500 Server error. It is OK, because server cannot process the request. But server logs me this: [13:17:03,846] INFO  xxx.HomeController  - received body: %7B%7D=

Comment: What you send with `data` needs to be `key = value` pairs.

Comment: if i set data: {'z':'a'}, the data sending is not realized (without errors in console). But if I also change processData to true, the server receives "z=a". But I need quotes, so it is not OK for me

Comment: Try removing "{}" with ""

Comment: The thread is named "I cannot stop AJAX from escaping request body I pass", so I need these brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.

First issue is part of the CORS restriction. For most cases this setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*" is sufficient. But in this case (posting JSON body), some additional headers are required. Here is the Java code for setting all of them:

```
response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept" );
response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
```

The other part of the issue is AJAX request. Here is the working code:

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify({foo: "BAR"});
$.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
         alert( "error  while making ajax call. Error parameters are, " +
               "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus +
               ";\n errorThrown: " + errorThrown +
               ";\n jqXHR: " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) );
    },     
    url: ajax_url,
    data: post_data,
    contentType: 'test/json',
    type: "POST"
});
```

P.S. #1 The provided code is tested with Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer browsers and works fine.
P.S. #2 The best place for the java code is in a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 'processData' to **true** AND you also need **no quotes AND** do not assign 'dataType'.

Setting 'dataType' to 'text' forces jQuery to pass a plain text-string.

**Here is an example of how you should pass your data:**

```
  var post_data = {foo: "BAR", lorem: "ipsum"};
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://my-server-name.com:8002/store_test',
    data: post_data,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: if I send this way, the body of the request is empty. If I pass data: {'z':'a'}, server receives "z=a". But I need quotes, so it is not OK for me

Comment: what is the body, received on server side?

Comment: I just figured out that you do not even have to set the data-type. See update above.

Comment: INFO  zzz.HomeController  - received body: foo=BAR&lorem=ipsum -> no quotes in my side

Comment: so your question is answered?

Comment: Noooo, I need the QUOTES in the request body. I need to put free test in request body and server to get this text untouched. But anything makes converts my request in POST style of passing values

Comment: "foo=BAR&lorem=ipsum" is the expected raw POST data... what else do you expect?

Comment: I need some kind of JSON formated text in the request body. Most easy thing is to get '{}', or '{"z":"a"}'

Comment: okay what you want is to pass an json-encoded string? Then pass JSON.stringify(post_data) instead of post_data.

Comment: beacause this do not works:

Code:
var post_data = JSON.stringify({foo: "BAR", lorem: "ipsum"});
$.post("http://zzz.com:8002/store_test2", post_data );

Result:
HomeController  - received body: %7B%22foo%22%3A%22BAR%22%2C%22lorem%22%3A%2
2ipsum%22%7D=; length=56

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jquery Post.

```
$.post("http://my-server-name.com:8002/store_test", { 
        //Your post data
       //data:"hi",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);

    }).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
    });
```

Comment: Hi pal,

I have this code:
var post_data = {foo: "BAR", lorem: "ipsum"};
$.post("http://svn.nasv.in:8002/store_test2", post_data );

The result is the same body without quotes. Anything makes URL escaping on everything I pass :(

Comment: Plz check your Server file whether print this characters. Save that file as UTF-8

Comment: Symbols '{' and '}' are not only UTF8 characters, but ASCII also, so the encoding is not issue. But modded server to print the length of the request body, and i get the exact value 19: HomeController  - received body: foo=BAR&lorem=ipsum; length=19

Comment: my first comment to your answer is the result of code, you have posted. Please read what I write you.

Comment: Did you include this in the page <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

Comment: the transfer data is not page, but JSON. This is mention in the question